# Change size of uml class frame when using IntelliJ uml diagram

Tags: intellij-idea, class-diagram

Is there any way to manually enlarge the size of the class frame when working with the IntelliJ diagram tool.

When marked the class gets a yellow border, however it is not possible to just drag the edge of the border to enlarge.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry, as far as I know there is no way to do that. Please vote for [this bug](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-102335).